# Excel vlookup help or something else

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is one I hope is easy have a workbook excel 2010, I have sheet 1 and sheet 2 both have column  A and B with information in them actually all numbers.
example :
   A
3451876 
   B
877-0151754

like 500 lines in each sheet.

I need to see if one number in column A from either sheet are actually on either sheet and if so i need it to tell me something yes no N/A or duplicate the number.
Just so long as I can see if one number from either sheets column A is on the other sheet column A.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with VLOOKUP as you guessed.
Add two helper columns next to your origiginal data, one for the result and one for vlookup to find something (might be possible to do that better)
Let's say D is the results column and you have 7 lines.
For D1:

```
VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$C$7,3,FALSE)
```

It will show you the corresponding content of column C on sheet two or an error if there is no corresponding entry. See if that get's you far enough.